# What can I wish a person who recently had a haircut?

Tags: phrase-requests

In my native language, we use a phrase that roughly means "get well" if we notice that someone has had a haircut. When I encounter such a situation with a friend living in the UK, I really don't know what to say.

Is there any phrase (or expression) that includes a wish rather than a compliment?

Comment: This sounds more like a cultural thing than a language issue. In America we don't wish people anything after getting a haircut. We just compliment them on how nice it looks.

Comment: So it would help if you told us what country your friend is in. Maybe there's something similar in their culture.

Comment: _Nice haircut!_ is enough

Comment: Apparently, Turkish barbers are not to be trifled with. [timetravelturtle.com/turkish-haircut-shave-istanbul](https://www.timetravelturtle.com/turkish-haircut-shave-istanbul/) - [birchbox.com/guide/article/a-traditional-turkish-shave](https://www.birchbox.com/guide/article/a-traditional-turkish-shave). I've never had a shave but if I do, now I'll be looking for a Turk. - If that's not it (being manhandled by another man), is there something religious going on about cutting hair?

Comment: It sounds to me as though your native language is doing what we do (in the UK, at least) when someone sneezes. We say 'bless you' for some odd, or ancient, reason. Perhaps your native language has adopted a meaning from Samson who lost his vigour when he lost his hair. So people need to 'get well' after a haircut has relieved them of some vigour.

Comment: @Barmar My friend is in the UK.

Comment: @Mazura I don't think there is something religious. The same phrase (in Turkish) is also used for someone who has had a shower.

Comment: The best compliment to an Englishman just back from a haircut is not to mention it to him, as if it's something significant to be mentioned.

Comment: Could you look at that again, in both your own language and English, please?

If there could be a useful translation, that would depend on "get well" applying not to every but only to bad haircuts… this has nothing to do with wishes rather than compliments, 
 
If you like the guy’s haircut, why not say so?

If you don’t like the guy’s haircut, why not talk about something else?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I guess haircut was associated with health hundreds years ago (Turkish culture), that's why such a phrase is used. Maybe "get well" is not a good translation, but simply health is wished in Turkish. That phrase doesn't tell if the haircut is good or bad.

Comment: Jolly good, ahmedus. How does that relate to English, please? When "get well" is not, what might be a good translation, please?

When "simply health" is wished in Turkish, what does that mean?

When whatever phrase doesn't tell if the haircut is good or bad what, usefully, could it mean in any language; English, Turkish, or whatever?

Turkish culture - not language - might well encompass "get well" meaning "simply health" is wished whether the haircut is good or bad.

English doesn’t understand what you’re saying.

Comment: If I notice someone has a new coat or other major clothing article I might say "wear it in good health" but I can't think of anything parallel for a haircut. I'd stick with a generic compliment.

Comment: Greek and Turkish are notorious for having formulaic wishes for just about anything new in a person's life, and that is indeed a cultural thing.

Comment: The Greek expression for haircuts (as well as new clothes) means "with health", implying "may you have the good health to enjoy it". So in a roundabout way, it means "enjoy!" Like @arp said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ‘wishes’ that go with haircuts, in the UK.

A normal thing to say would be ‘nice haircut!’ Or ‘I love your hair’ often followed by ‘where did you get it done?’.

But that’s about it.